# Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have some issues with a JavaScript portion that I have added to my WordPress footer.php:

```
<script>
jQuery('.showPosts').on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('hidePosts')) {
        jQuery(this).children('div').hide();
        jQuery(this).removeClass('hidePosts');
        jQuery(this).children('.greekCross').html('&#10010;');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).children('div').show();
        jQuery(this).addClass('hidePosts');
        jQuery(this).children('.greekCross').html('&#160;&#10145;');
    }
});
jQuery('.search-field').attr('placeholder','TYPE IN SEARCH TAGS...');
jQuery('.videoText').remove();
jQuery('.ytVideoContainer').addClass('left');
jQuery('.catContainer').addClass('right');
jQuery('.catContainer').addClass('noMarginTop');
var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)');
if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at least 767px
    jQuery('.relatedVideoThumb').show();
} else {
    jQuery('.postcontentTitle').insertBefore('.catContainer');
    jQuery('.postcontent').insertBefore('.catContainer');
    jQuery('.relatedVideoThumb').hide();
}
var winWidth  = 0;
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    winWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if (winWidth < 768) {
        jQuery('.postcontentTitle').insertBefore('.catContainer');
        jQuery('.postcontent').insertBefore('.catContainer');
        jQuery('.relatedVideoThumb').hide();
    } else {
    jQuery('.catContainer').insertBefore('.postcontent');
    jQuery('.catContainer').insertBefore('.postcontentTitle');
    jQuery('.relatedVideoThumb').show();
    }
});
jQuery('.site-header .home-link').css('border', '0');
</script>
```

Every time I reload the page I receive in the Google Chrome Console the following:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Being minified for optimization purposes I had to look into Firefox Firebug extension to see where exactly is this unexpected end of input. I received the following:

```
SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement
); }});jQuery('.site-header .home-link').css('border', '0');
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't see where I could had done something wrong, I've more than double check it but I am unable to find the mistake so any guidance or solution is more than welcomed.

Comment: Your script block is correct, the error is somewhere else. Try to remove this `<script>` block and check in google chrome again...

Comment: Is that the whole javascript code ? Maybe your code starts with `$(document).ready(function(){` .. so the `})` is missing.

Comment: I figure it out eventually. It's because the minify plugin that I use (WP Super Minify) somehow creates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement`

This error message tells you to add a `}` is missing at this point.

Try to add it.

I suppose you will also have to add `)` to complete your javascript code.

Comment: I've tried but it wasn't the fix. Like i've mentioned above, the wordpress plugin that I use to minify the js files creates the issue.

Comment: so if the error is related to the minifier, it should be changed. maybe an update exists from wordpress, or the library used.

Comment: I've actually reactivated and remove the if statement for  `mq.matches` and for some weird reason the error is gone but the functionality is working like it should.